# Count a Numeric Varchar Column Stored in Base Six

Tags: php, mysql, modular-arithmetic

I have a table that stores a numeric value in a `VARCHAR` column, this column is storing values calculated in base six math. Meaning:

> 3.5 = 3 + 5 / 6
>
> 9.4 = 3.4 + 5.6

**I need to get the sum of the values in these rows.** I know I need to separate them based on id, then add specific ids' base-sixe numbers together, however I don't know where to start. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: *"is there any easy way to do it?"* - Define "easy". There are many ways of doing this. Ever heard of `count()`, or `sum()` or the `+` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- How would `+` do this? He doesn't want to use ordinary arithmetic rules.

Comment: @Barmar it's an indirect example. Sum = col1 + col2 + col3. question's unclear/too broad.

Comment: It seems like his real question is how to convert `3.5` to `3.833333` before adding it.

Comment: *"If I want to get the sum of the values in these rows"* - *"value in a varchar column"* makes it even harder to calculate here, no? I honestly don't know why integers are stored in varchar to start with.

Comment: @Fred-ii- They're not integers. They're fractions, but the part after the `.` is sixths instead of tenths.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough. so... what say we clear our comments to make room for potential other comments? if I see yours deleted, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Is `5.6` really a valid value in the column? Shouldn't that be `6.0`?

Comment: First why would you store a numeric value in a varchar column in the first place? second, what does the table structure look like? third what attempts have you made? fourth you will have to convert it to base 10 before using a `SUM()` aggregate function, but I would recommend you change the table design to make this a simpler feat. AKA your table is not really normalized, you should add a column that has the fraction offset and store the number by itself. 3 goes in one column and 5/6 goes in another column.

Comment: @Barmer no that's a typo sorry, should be 6.0

Comment: @John Ruddell that seems the most efficient way of doing it thanks

Comment: @Fred-ii- they shouldn't be stored in a varchar, but they're floats not ints, and I didn't want to save it as a decimal in a float column because it's base-6. I define 'easy' as brevity and clarity of code, without compromising on effectiveness.

Comment: @MichealOMaolain It is a much better way to do it. Although Barmars answer does solve your problem, I wouldn't ever put that code into production ever. You should really consider updating your table to add a column that stores the base 6 division.. or even two columns with the numerator and the denominator.. that way you can calculate the division yourself when you want to and not when you don't want to. Just my two cents on the matter though. I'll throw you a +1 since it is a different question that others may need help with in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert these numbers to ordinary numbers with:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '.', 1) + IF(LOCATE(column, '.'), SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '.', -1)/6, 0)
```

You can then use this expression in `SUM()` to add all the column in the table, or you can use it with `+` to add different columns to each other. E.g.

```
SELECT SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '.', 1) + IF(LOCATE(column, '.'), SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '.', -1)/6, 0)) AS total
FROM yourTable
```

If you also need to convert the sum back to your base 6 fraction representation, you can use:

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(total), '.', ROUND(MOD(total, 1) * 6)
```

So a full query might look like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(total), '.', ROUND(MOD(total, 1) * 6) AS total
FROM (SELECT SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '.', 1) + 
                 IF(LOCATE(column, '.'), SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '.', -1)/6, 0)) AS total
      FROM yourTable) as subquery
```

Comment: How would I implement this in a  query though?

Comment: @Micheal O Maolain - If you mean my Statement, so there is nothing to do. Only now you can sum the new field in the table

Comment: @MichealOMaolain I've added a full query that shows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new Virtual column to the Table where MySQL stores the normalized Value every time you change it. So you can sum this Column.

Change only the Tablename and the name for the Column 'col'

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD COLUMN norm float AS (FLOOR(col) + MOD(col, 1) / 0.6 ) PERSISTENT;
```

You can also put a index on the new field if you want.

Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: I get an error when I try to execute this query `ALTER TABLE own_bowling ADD COLUMN overs_norm float AS (FLOOR(overs) + MOD(overs, 1) / 0.6 ) PERSISTENT;` _#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (FLOOR(overs) + MOD(overs, 1) / 0.6 ) PERSISTENT' at line 2_

Comment: sorry, ist to old. if can do, switch to MariaDB 10.1.9